# In Fast-DDS, Set IP From Localhost to Certain LAN

Tags: c++, routes, data-distribution-service, ros2

I am newbie in DDS and C++, and I used fastrtps to run dds code(dynamic example) in a raspberry(ubuntu server), which was successful. However, when I move subscribe part to another raspberry, two raspberries cannot find each other.

So far, I guess there are two reason:

1. My cellphone(android) has firewall. Should I change cellphone to switch?
2. I should use API to set raspberry-self ip, but I cannot find it suit for the example code
   [result of command lsof -i -P -n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXwuO.png)

This is example code [DynamicHelloWorldExample](https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-DDS/tree/master/examples/C%2B%2B/DynamicHelloWorldExample).

Thanks ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I turn off firewall(command below) on both raspberries, not cellphone.

`sudo ufw disable`

Thanks every one trying to help me.